# Confused about "k-form"

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Lee's *Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature* states the following on page 14:

> We let $\Lambda ^k (V)$ denote the space of covariant alternating
> $k$-tensors on $V$, also called $k$-*covectors* or (exterior)
> $k$-*forms*.

This confused me because, for me, a $k$-form is an alternating covariant tensor **field** of degree $k$, not just a tensor.

Later, Lee defines the following:

> the *bundle of* $k$-*forms* is $\Lambda^k M := \coprod_{p\in M}\Lambda^k(T_p M).$

> a *differential* $k$-*form* is a smooth section of  $\Lambda^k M$.

According to this, am I correct in assuming the following?

- A $k$-form without "differential" is just an alternating multilinear map from a vector space to the space of scalars.
- A **differential** $k$-form is what I have been thinking a $k$-form is, that is, an alternating covariant tensor field of degree $k$.
- Some people omit "differential" for some reason when they actually mean differential $k$-form.

If I am correct, is it a common naming method?

Comment: *Most* people (unless it's algebraists working just in an algebraic context) mean *differential* form when they talk about forms on domains or manifolds. Otherwise, *most* people will say bilinear or multilinear form if they are restricting to the vector space setting.

Comment: Also, another notational matter: the use of $\Lambda^k(V)$ here is wrong (it appears in Spivak’s *Calculus on Manifolds* as well, and conflicts perfectly with its usual meaning in abstract algebra). The correct notation is $\bigwedge^k(V^*)$, with the $*$ (also as a personal pet peeve, I abhor $\Lambda$, and much prefer $\bigwedge$). Lee modifies this in his second edition Riemannian geometry text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct assuming what you enumerated. It is very common, from my experience.

Note also that, for some authors, a *differential k-form* is just a section of $\Lambda^k M$, whereas a *smooth/differentiable differential k-form* is a smooth/differentiable section of $\Lambda^k M$. For practical reasons, once the reader gets comfortable with the naming, all the preceding adjectives are usually ommited for the sake of clarity or brevity and one just says *k-form*.